# Possible result of integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(x^{\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{x}}-1\right)dx=0$: Too good to be true?

Tags: trigonometry, improper-integrals, exponentiation

This question is far beyond my level but let me propose it for the aesthetic. First the result have been found with Desmos so there is a possibility to have a wrong result.

Claim:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(x^{\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{x}}-1\right)dx=^?0$$

It doesn't seems to be trivial at first glance but make me a comment if so.

Some tought :

Following an idea due to user Momo here [Prove or disprove that : $x^{\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}}> \sin\left(x\right)+\frac{1}{x-1}$ for $x\geq \pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217591/prove-or-disprove-that-x-frac-sin-leftx-rightx-sin-leftx-right)

We have using the well-know identity on the real $e^x\geq x+1$ :

$$x^\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\geq 1+\ln(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

To have a better  approximation we integrate on $[1,\infty)$ it gives :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(x^{\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{x}}-1\right)dx\geq I=\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^{\frac{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{x}}-1\right)dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}1+\ln(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-1 dx$$

It gives us :

$$I\simeq 0.075122-0.616781=-0.541659$$

Now using the result due to user Sangchul lee we see that the integral converges but it's not equal to zero (so be careful with software like Desmos in a such case)

Question: Can we hope to find a closed form or an interesting series like the Sophomore's dream ?

Comment: Maybe this [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xiIsPEqyTqU)  will help.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What do you think about ?

Comment: Numerical integration with the help of *Mathematica* seems to suggest that the integral is close to $-0.16$, definitely not zero. (Note: this is highly oscillatory, and numerical methods can fail badly at such problems. Nevertheless, the same calculation with machine precision and with 30-digit precision gives essentially the same answers, so my bet is the integral is not zero.)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki. Are you sure of the result ? Look at  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NIntegrate%5Bx%5E%28Sin%5BPi+x%5D%2Fx%29+-+1%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%2C+++WorkingPrecision+-%3E10%5D and play with the working precision.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: No, I am not sure, this is just "experimental maths". :-) That said, integrating from zero to infinity for this kind of integrands leads nowhere. I will describe what I did in an answer below momentarily, this is too long for a comment.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki. I am waiting for it. Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: We can **show** that the integral is negative. Indeed, we may decompose the integral into the sum $$A_0+B_1+B_2+R_3$$ where \begin{align*}f(x)&=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}\log x,\\A_0&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(e^{f(x)}-1-f(x)-\frac{1}{2!}f(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x&&\approx-6.89518\\B_1&=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x&&\approx-2.70483,\\B_2&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2!}f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x&&\approx9.43770,\\\left|R_3\right|&\leq\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{1/e}}{3!}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)^3\,\mathrm{d}x&&\approx0.0902917.\end{align*} From this, the integral is bounded from above by $\approx-0.072021$.

Comment: The above decomposition is chosen because the integrals $B_1$ and $B_2$ and the bound for $|R_3|$ can be computed *explicitly*, thereby allowing to find their numerical values within any desired accuracy. For example, $$B_1=-\frac{\pi}{2}(\gamma+\log\pi)$$ and $$|R_3|\leq\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{1/e}}{3!}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)^3\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{e^{1/e}}{16}.$$ The expression for $B_2$ is more complicated, but is still written as a closed form involving $\gamma$ and $\pi$.

Comment: @SangchulLee What is your conclusion ?

Comment: @ErikSatie, Let me cite my first comment: "We can **show** that the integral is negative. ... The integral is bounded from above by $\approx-0.072021$."

Comment: @SangchulLee So it's not zero and Desmos was wrong my bad !

Comment: No worries :) Numerical integration on oscillatory, slow-decaying functions is notoriously hard, so I can't blame Desmos for that.

Comment: @SangchulLee Do you want to make an answer ? it would be appropriate for other people I think .Again thanks !

Comment: @SangchulLee, did you accidentally omit a square from ${1\over2!}f(x)^2$ in your definition of $_0$?

Comment: Erik Satie, no new answers can be added to a closed question. That is why I wrote up comments instead. Hope it helped anyway :) / @BarryCipra, Indeed that is a typo. Thank you!

Comment: @ErikSatie, one thing that might help get the question reopened would be to rewrite it so as to ask if the given integral is positive, negative, or equal to $0$ (instead of asserting that it's equal to $0$ and asking how to show it). I'd also recommend explaining what you did with Desmos to make you think the value might be $0$. (It's not even obvious, to me at least, that the improper integral converges.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Question reopened !

Answer (score 2):

This will be a “long comment”. I tried a few techniques, but none were the right way. It seems like the main way to complete it is through basic algebra and integral properties. It is harder than it looks.

[Integral of function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xaskx1g1fa)

Using odd and even rules of functions brings back the original integral. Note that sin(-x)=sin(x), hence it is an even function.

$$\mathrm{f(x)=Even(x)+Odd(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}\implies I=\int_0^\infty x^\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x}-1dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty  x^\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x}+ (-x)^\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x}+x^\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x}-(-x)^\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x}-2dx}$$

There is a way to put it into another form using the [Abel-Plana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) formula. Note the integrand value has the limit value of -1 at x=0. The sum part of the formula has all index>0 terms as 0, so it is written here already:

$$\mathrm{\int_0^\infty x^\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x}-1dx=-\frac32+i\int_0^\infty \frac{(ix)^\frac{sinh(\pi x)}{x}-(-ix)^\frac{sinh(\pi x)}{x}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx\mathop =^?0}$$

$\large{\text{Possible Proof:}}$

$$\mathrm{\int_0^\infty x^\frac{sin(\pi x)}{x}-1dx=\lim_{b,n\to\infty,b\gg n}\frac bn \sum_{k=1}^n \left[\left(\frac{kb}{n}\right)^{\frac{sin \left(\frac{\pi kb}{n}\right)}{\frac{kb}{n}}} -1\right] =0}$$

This uses the [Riemann Sum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) definition of an integral. Assuming b is a large number or $\infty$, b can always be made larger than n. In the limit, the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eu8zhchmph) gets closer to 0 with larger n. Even though the sum had a greater chance of evaluating to 0 for larger n, there still is a chance for an n chosen to evaluate to a partial sum S with $|S|\le N$ with N as the upper bound for S. This chance for evaluation to another number other than 0 decreases as $n\to \infty$. Therefore, when b and n both approach infinity with the upper integral bound b growing arbitrarily larger than, the partial sum S gets closer to 0. This means that the integral is 0.

[image]
Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but again it seems too good to be true  .Have you tried some numerical experiments ?

Comment: @ErikSatie Please see the new non-rigorous proof. This is an example of numerical approximation.

Comment: I was not thinking about the Riemann sum but it's really coool !!

Comment: Can you propose it on maths overflow ?

Comment: Well as you wish and  you can post my question and your answer together ;-)

Comment: Sorry I believed it was true from your answer but it's still complicated again sorry my bad !!

Comment: Notice the “possible proof”.

Comment: The integral is *not* zero. See the comment of user Sangchul Lee.

Comment: @K.defaoite Yes, but this was posted before the other solution. It also still shows the integral is “near” $0$. Plus others have upvoted indicating interest. It should be clear the integral is not $0$.

Comment: " Note that sin(-x)=sin(x), hence it is an even function.", this is false, do you mean to say instead that $\mathrm{sinc}(x)$ is even??

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a strong indication that the integral is *not* zero.

Evaluating such integrals numerically with *Mathematica* is a bit tricky, because a rather obvious call to `NIntegrate[..., {x,0,Infinity}]` usually leads nowhere. Instead, it is often better to evaluate the integrals over sufficiently many finite intervals and see how the integral changes.

So, here is the initial code:

```
ClearAll[int];
int[0] = 0;
For[k = 1, k <= 100, k++,
  int[k] = int[k-1] +
    NIntegrate[
      Exp[Log[x] Sin[Pi x] / x] - 1,
      {x, 1000 (k-1), 1000 k}
    ]
]
ListPlot[int /@ Range[100]]
```

It stores the integrals over $[0, 1000k]$ as `int[k]` and then plots the results for $k$ equal to $1$ through $100$.

However, Mathematica complains about insufficient speed of convergence, and suggests increasing recursion limit and working precision. Let us do so:

```
ClearAll[int];
int[0] = 0;
For[k = 1, k <= 100, k++,
  int[k] = int[k-1] +
    NIntegrate[
      Exp[Log[x] Sin[Pi x] / x] - 1,
      {x, 1000 (k-1), 1000 k},
      MaxRecursion -> 30,
      WorkingPrecision -> 30
    ]
]
ListPlot[int /@ Range[100]]
```

Now this takes *a bit* longer to evaluate (nearly five minutes on my laptop), but luckily *Mathematica's* complains are gone. Here is what comes out:

[image: plot of the integral]

Interestingly, with the above method, the result does not seem to depend essentially on the fine-tuning parameters: we have

```
int[100] = -0.160888472353482801858094440731
```

with the above choice, and

```
int[100] = -0.160889
```

with default parameters (and lots of warning messages). For the record:

```
NIntegrate[Exp[Log[x] Sin[Pi x]/x] - 1, {x, 0, Infinity}] = -40.5999
```

is completely off, and

```
NIntegrate[Exp[Log[x] Sin[Pi x]/x] - 1, {x, 0, Infinity},
  MaxRecursion -> 30, WorkingPrecision -> 30] = 34.8902020565215540843737276445
```

is not any better. One can likely play with other integration strategies and get a better result, but I did not try to do that.

Comment: Thanks !! I have another method to check it's really not smart but maybe good .I check the value on WA with small gap $(a,a+100)$ see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Integral%22%2C+%22rangestart%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Integral%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22x%5E%28sin%28x*pi%29%2Fx%29-1%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Integral%22%2C+%22rangeend%22%7D+-%3E%22240%22 .It is correct as approach ?

Comment: Now maybe we can try to evaluate the integral?

Comment: @TymaGaidash: I would be *very* surprised if a closed-form expression existed for this integral.

Comment: @ErikSatie: Consider asking Sangchul Lee to write up his comment as an answer, and accepting that one.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I agree, it would be easier to find a series solution or other solution with the “comment answer”. Now if this was posted as a solution.